# C# Advanced Tag Parsing

Tags: c#, parsing, tags

We are developing an application and we need the ability to generate text strings from tags, which can be used for example to generate csv files, sql statements, etc..., which tags represent a source of data within the software.

This is designed to give the end-user maximum flexibility into how to extract data from the software, it is coupled with modules like file writer, Database connector, MS Word document parser, etc...

The Basic idea is to have a tag format like this `{SourceObject.Item("formatting")}`

Which tag can then be used as `INSERT INTO mydb (myfield) VALUES ("{SourceObject.Item("formatting")}");`

Where it gets tricky is data we might have an array of source Object, which means the tags can start to become fairly complex:

`{SourceObject(12).Item("formatting")}`

or

`{SourceObject("ITEM17").Item("formatting")}`

as an example to generate a text file with a specific name:

`myfile {System.Date("DD_MM_YY HH:NN")}.txt` would yield `myfile 08_08_19 12:22.txt`

We could write down a parser from scratch, but I believe this type of parsing is relatively common, perhaps a similar approach or an existing parser could do the job ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your goal without additional libraries, all of the examples can be handled with a simple Regular Expression: `{([\w]+)(?:\("([^"]+)"\)|\(([^\)]+)\))*\.([\w]+)\("([^"]+)"\)}`

This RegEx cover all cases you posted:

- `{SourceObject(12).Item("formatting")}` yelds the following:

  - Group 1: `SourceObject`
  - Group 3: `12`
  - Group 4: `Item`
  - Group 5: `formatting`
- `{SourceObject("ITEM17").Item("formatting")}` yelds the following:

  - Group 1: `SourceObject`
  - Group 2: `ITEM17`
  - Group 4: `Item`
  - Group 5: `formatting`
- `myfile {System.Date("DD_MM_YY HH:NN")}.txt` yelds the following:

  - Group 1: `System`
  - Group 4: `Date`
  - Group 5: `DD_MM_YY HH:NN`
- And so on..

In C# it is as easy as the following code:

```
private static Regex tagParsing = new Regex(
    @"{([\w]+)(?:\(""([^""]+)""\)|\(([^\)]+)\))*\.([\w]+)\(""([^""]+)""\)}", 
    RegexOptions.Compiled);

public static void TestMethod()
{
    Match m = tagParsing.Match(@"myfile {System.Date(""DD_MM_YY HH:NN"")}.txt");
}
```

You just need to remember the `RegexOptions.Compiled` option and to reuse the same instance of the compiled Regex, or otherwise you will have a performance hit.

Comment: Thanks, How about performance? I have had bad experience with regex as being really slow. Imagine parsing a 15 pages word documents.

Comment: It is difficult to answer a such generic question: the more specific is the Regular Expression, the better it will perform. For instance, if you know that your tokens can only contain letters, you would better swap `\w` with `A-Za-z`, and so on. And this is generally true in all Regex implementations. In C# as written in the answer if you accidentally forgot to use `RegexOptions.Compiled` or didn't reuse the compiled instance, I'm sure you had slow performance and heavy usage of CPU (and/or RAM).
We user Regular Expression for datasets bigger than a 15 pages Word document without issues.

Comment: Tested it, a 1000 words document would take about 2s with the compiled option, but I think it is acceptable.